# How to correctly lint .sass files using stylelint-webpack-plugin (with webpack 2)?

Tags: webpack, sass, stylelint

I'm actually trying to use a linter for my *.sass* files, in a Webpack 2 project. So I'm using "stylelint-webpack-plugin", but no matter how I configure it, I always get warnings/errors about semicolons (which are not relevant with .sass syntax).
It seems that poscss-sass package doesn't do the job... Is there any solution for people using .sass (not .scss) syntax?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postcss-sass` parser is very new and its compatibility with stylelint is still being [evaluated](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/2486). It is not yet bundled within stylelint, and is therefore not available via `stylelint-webpack-plugin`'s [`syntax` option](https://github.com/JaKXz/stylelint-webpack-plugin#options).

> I always get warnings/errors about semicolons (which are not relevant with .sass syntax).

This is because, in the absence of the `postcss-sass` parser, the *standard* PostCSS parser is attempting to parse your SASS code. It expects declarations within declaration blocks to be separated by semicolons.

A `custom-syntax` option is provided by stylelint itself. Therefore, if you like, you can *experiment* with the `postcss-sass` parser by using the stylelint CLI:

```
stylelint "**/*.sass" --custom-syntax postcss-sass
```

This should resolve any *syntax* errors you're getting regarding semi-colons.

If you're using `stylelint-config-standard`, you should also [turn off any rules](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard#using-the-config-with-sugarss-syntax) that check braces and semicolons.

---

As an alternative to SASS, you could use [SugarSS](https://github.com/postcss/sugarss). It is an indent-based CSS syntax that is compatible with stylelint and available within `stylelint-webpack-plugin`.