# How to lint ".sass" (tab style) with stylelint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, stylelint

I use recommend stylelint setting:

```
// .stylelint.config.js (I use Nuxt.js to build project)
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        'stylelint-config-standard'
    ],
    rules: {}
}
```

And I write simple SASS file:

```
// app.sass
body
    background: #eee
```

But get error message:

[image]

Dose stylelint not support `.sass` file?

---

Another questions is autofix on autoSave in VS Code

```
// setting.json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
}
```

But it's not working when I save `.sass` file.

[image]

Comment: Try this syntax `body { background: #eee }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly lint .sass files using stylelint-webpack-plugin (with webpack 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570365/how-to-correctly-lint-sass-files-using-stylelint-webpack-plugin-with-webpack-2)